# Gather user input from outbound calls using Twilio

Tags: c#, .net, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I want to start developing an alarming/alerting service using C# / .Net that is going to call an user using Twilio.

The call will tell the user an alarm has been activated.

Now I want the user to be able to provide feedback to the system by using Keypad/DTMF tones to let the system know he will be:

1. Solving the alarm
2. Not solving the alarm
3. Call him back in a short period of time

Is this possible with outbound calls using Twilio?

All demo's I found about user input/feedback is when there's an incoming call, not an outbound call.
If there is any documentation about it I would be pleased to find it.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible with Programmable Voice. Here is the basic sequence:

1. Your app initiates a REST API call to Twilio
2. Twilio asks your app for instructions via a webhook
3. Your server replies with instructions written in TwiML

see https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/quickstart/csharp for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

I'm a bit late but just in case anyone else needs it, as I was in the same situation a few days ago.

I've added my answer with how can it be done in NodeJS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77523756/642771). But more or less here are the steps:

1. You invoke de voice call (client.calls.create(params)). This places the voice call asynchronously. In this call you'll say something to the user and wait for the answer, and the TwiML code for this is something like this:

```xml
<Response> 
    <Say>You have been called by an automated system. </Say>
    <Pause length="1"/>
    <Gather input="dtmf" timeout="5" numDigits="1" action="<URL>/voicewebhook" method="POST">
        <Say>Press 1 for accepting or 5 to decline, please.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

TwiML uses verbs to descibe actions, and for gathering user input you need to use the `Gather` verb. You can nest inside the options for the user that will be enumerated before they have to press a key. You have then somehow tell Twilio where the flow should be redirected when action is needed. This can be achieved by adding `action` attribute to the `Gather` verb, in a similar way you do it when using HTML forms.

2. You have to create the code on `<URL>/voicewebhook` to manage user input and finish the voice call.

And that's all.