# Gather DTMF inputs from user via an outbound call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

I have a very simple question about gathering DTMF inputs from users via an outbound call made to them. I am describing the requirement below.

**Main Requirement**
I have a python script that makes outbound calls to a particular number. The person accepts the call. I say the information to them via the twiml configured. The person hears the info and presses a key on their phone. I want to capture that key input and just print it as an output using my script.

**The problem**
I am able to make the outbound call using the *client.calls.create* method described here. https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-python
But I am unable to gather the digits. The examples I have seen online are describing how to achieve gathering inputs with a running web application. I am NOT using this method.
I am looking to get this done via a simple script. I initiate the outgoing call from the Twilio number via the script. I don't intend to use any web applications or webhooks here.

I am putting the code below that works until making the call and reciting the options to the user.

How can I get this done? Is this possible? Many thanks.

```py
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import Gather, VoiceResponse, Say

account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']='XXXXX'
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']='YYYYY'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
                        twiml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Gather input="dtmf" timeout="5" numDigits="1"><Say>Please press 1 for sales</Say></Gather></Response>',
                        to='Destination_Number',
                        from_='My_Twilio_Number'
                    )




#TODO - How to Gather Digits from the user????
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are many ways to interact with a phone call through Twilio, but when you are trying to take user input through [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) all of them require Twilio to be able to notify you of the digits that the user pressed. Since this is an asynchronous action, the basic method of doing so is via a webhook, an HTTP request, sent to a web application that you control.

If you do not want to host an application that responds to webhooks yourself, you could achieve this flow using [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio), which is a drag and drop editor for communications flows, or using [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions), which is a serverless environment where you can respond to incoming HTTP requests with JavaScript functions.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. First of all, as it has been previously answered, voice calls are asynchronous, yo when placing the call you can't do anything more. You need to define a webhook: a URL that will lead Twillio to a piece of code that can manage the call.

In my tests this is what I've made. First of all, I've changed a bit the TwiML code:

```js
twiml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <Response>
           <Gather input="dtmf" timeout="5" numDigits="1"
                   action="<url_to_your_code_absolute_or_relative>/myvoicewebhook" method="POST">
               <Say>Please press 1 for sales</Say>
           </Gather>
       </Response>',
```

The URL used here can be absolute or relative to where this piece of code is included.

After this, you have to create the code that will act as the webhook. On a route file you'll have something like this:

```js
router.post('/myvoicewebhook', controller.myVoiceWebhookMethod);
```

Here it's important that you define it with the same HTTP method that you have used previously in your TwiML code.

And finally your code will be something like this:

```js
controller.myVoiceWebhookMethod =  (request, response) => {
    const twiml = new VoiceResponse();
    switch (request.body.Digits) {
        case 1:
            twiml.say("You have pushed button 1");
            break;
        ....
        default:
            twiml.say("I didn't understand you");
            break;
    }    


    response.type('xml');
    response.send(twiml.toString());
    return;
};
```

When the user clicks on the number panel, you get the numbers in the `Digits` attribute of the body that's included in the request. You'll need to add this to your `app.js` file to access to this property more easily

```js
const urlencoded = require('body-parser').urlencoded;
[...]
const express = require('express'); 
app.use(urlencoded({extended: false}));
[...]
```

When user hears the message asking for a key press, and user clicks on a number, Twillio redirects this to the `action` URL defined on initial TwiML portion of code. This action then retrieves the numbers clicked by the user in the `Digits` property. Be careful with the initial uppercase letter, it has to be uppercase otherwise you'll be referencing to an unknnown property. When you have added to the TwiML response what you want the user to know you finally send this TwiML as the response to the initial request and the call is finished.